# Massive data out from server while using elasticsearch with couchbase

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, couchbase

I have a very strange problem. I am using Elasticsearch with Couchbase on windows azure cloud. I have configured couchbase plus elasticsearch on a single ubuntu machine (3.5 gb). I have put elasticsearch on auto indexing. I have a java application which talks to couchbase and elasticsearch.

The problem here is that i see a massive data out from servers to the tune to 500 GB in a single day which costs me dearly, like 80 $ a day.
I have tried redeploying the thing to other box as well but the result is same.

I also tried keeping elasticsearch and couchbase on different servers but that the data out is from both the servers.

I see around 400GB of data out from couchbase server and 200GB of dataout from elasticsearch server.

Any idea what could be the possible thing i am missing here.

Thanks
Vish

Comment: What do you mean "data out"? if both CB and ES on the same server all connections are local... please clarify to where your data being sent? Is it being sent to some remote unknown TCP/IP address?

Comment: Ideally that has to be the case. I did the setup on windows azure. Elasticsearch identifies the couchbase server running and attaches itself.
Now the information i have is from the reports provided by microsoft. It mentions that there is data out. My problem is that there is no data-in that ratio.
I cannot find out where the data have been sent out... 
Which makes me stuck and not able to use the boxes because of charge..
Any help is really welcome..

Comment: Try follow up with MS Azure support to have explanation of these statistics...could be bogus "data out" numbers...I would definitely dispute that (unless they provide TCP/IP statistics with source and destination logs)...also try disconnect/firewall that VM from internet and other networks except your session...to see if it changes anything. Also try to stop ES server process to see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen to a dev machine at our shop. Unfortunately our ElasticSearch was hacked and malware was sending out hundreds of GBs per day.

There are details about the exploit here:

http://www.vanimpe.eu/2014/07/09/elasticsearch-vulnerability-exploit/

You'll likely want to ditch that VM and start over. =(